# Characterization of distance between points in separable space

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

I want to prove that if $X$ is a separable metric space, then for all $x,y \in X$ and any dense set $\{x_i\}$, we can write:

$$d(x,y) = \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |d(x,x_i) - d(y,x_i) |.$$

Some attempts. One side: fix $x,y$, by denseness there exists a subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$ of $x_n$ such that $x_{n_{k}}$ converges to $x$. This implies
$$\sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |d(x,x_i) - d(y,x_i) | \geq \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |d(x,x_{n_{k}}) - d(y,x_{n_{k}}) | = d(x,y) $$
even if I am not even sure about how to justify the last passage since it's a supremum and not a limit. Moreover I cannot do the other inqeuality. How can I proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof for the inequality $d(x,y) \le \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |d(x,x_i) - d(y,x_i)|$ has the right idea, but as you noticed, it's not rigorous since you didn't justify that $\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |d(x,x_{n_{k}}) - d(y,x_{n_{k}}) | = d(x,y)$.

You can argue as follows instead : since $\{x_n\}$ is dense, you can have find a subfamily $\{x_{n_k}\}$ such that for all $k\ge1$, $d(x,x_{n_k})\le 1/k$. Furthermore, for all $k\ge 1$
$$\sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |d(x,x_i) - d(y,x_i) | \geq|d(x,x_{n_{k}}) - d(y,x_{n_{k}}) | \ge d(y,x_{n_k}) -d(x,x_{n_k}).\tag1 $$
And by triangle inequality
$$d(x,y)\le d(x,x_{n_k})+ d(x_{n_k},y)\implies d(y,x_{n_k})\ge d(x,y) - d(x,x_{n_k}) \tag2 $$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ together with the fact that $-d(x,x_{n_k})\ge -1/k$, we find
$$\sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |d(x,x_i) - d(y,x_i) | \ge d(y,x) -2d(x,x_{n_k})\ge d(y,x) -2/k, $$
and since this holds for any $k\ge1$, the desired inequality follows by letting $k\to\infty$.

---

To show that $d(x,y) \ge \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |d(x,x_i) - d(y,x_i)|$, apply the following

> **Reverse triangle inequality :** for all $x,y,z\in X$, we have
> $$d(x,y)\ge |d(x,z)-d(y,z)| $$

to some well chosen $z$ (make sure to prove the above inequality yourself if you didn't already know it).

Comment: Yes true! Thanks I shoud have kept going... One thing: the second inequality in (1) is just wlog? Two: the well chosen $z$ is indeed $x_i$ and then I take the sup on rhs, correct?

Comment: Re your first question : it is always true that $|a|\ge a$ for any real number $a$. Re your second question : yes, that's right ;)

Comment: But you inverted the signs on the rhs of (1), is it a typo then?

Comment: well, $|a|=|-a|$, so you can pick $a$ or $-a$ as a lower bound

Comment: Thanks :)......

Comment: One (last) question: couldn't I just have picked the sequence $x_{n_k}$ equal to the constant sequence $y$, and get the same result for the first part? Hence showing that the separability assumption is not necessary?

Comment: $y$ is a priori not part of the family $\{x_i\}$, so that's not a valid choice.

Comment: Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 8):

In any metric space $(X,d)$, you can easily prove that
[$$\sup_{z\in X}|d(x,z)-d(y,z)|=d(x,y).$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3388953)
If moreover $A$ is a dense subset of $X$ then
[$$\sup_{z\in X}f(z)=\sup_{z\in A}f(z)$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3827752)
for $f(z):=|d(x,z)-d(y,z)|$, because $f$ is continuous.

Comment: How would you prove the first statement in general?

Comment: @Porcupine Follow the first of the two links in my answer. I found it more educational to formulate these two general properties and link to their proofs, than reprove them (or their immediate corollary) in your particular case like the other answerer did.

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much!!

Comment: That was very kind of you to upvote 5 of my past answers all of a sudden, but I read [it is frowned upon](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) (and I think there is a bot which annihilates such serial up- or down- votes). I know you did this because you could not accept both answers, but these are the rules: you have to choose.

Comment: Oh, I just did it since I considered your answer more elegant than the first one: but the first one was useful since really solved where I got stuck. I would have accepted both if I could have done